# Trying to pass my search result from my search website to another search website

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass my search term from my site into the string of another site's URL link. This will allow the search to find books on my site and if it can't be found there the user would click a button that would take the string from the search field and pass it to the URL of MnLink.org. I know my sites code is as follows.

Search For:

I can't figure out what I am missing because I am new to HTML and a novice in JavaScript. I thought I could put the value or id in as a var in a script but I could not get that to work. below is what I have started but got stuck on, any help would be great.

https://mnlink.on.worldcat.org/search?='"style="padding-left:10px;background:#ffffff; border: solid black;">Continue Search

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a form with `method="get"` and `action="https://mnlink.on.worldcat.org/search"`.

EXAMPLE:

```
<form method="get" action="https://mnlink.on.worldcat.org/search">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="queryString" value="" />
    <button type="submit">
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/ojcvr0pv/)

**EDIT**

If you have to use an onClick event i suggest you to use Jquery: on `click()` you have to redirect your page with `window.location.href = 'https://mnlink.on.worldcat.org/search?queryString='` but you must add the value at the end of that String with `$("#INPUT_ID").val()`. See the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/ojcvr0pv/1/).

HTML:

```
<input title="Search For:" autofocus="false" accesskey="s" maxlength="256" tabindex="9" autocomplete="off" size="100" value="cats" id="q" name="q" type="text">

<button id="submit">
  Search
</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function() {
         window.location.href = 'https://mnlink.on.worldcat.org/search?queryString=' + $("#q").val();
    });
});
```

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/ojcvr0pv/1/).

Comment: Thanks that would work great, but the issue is I need to have it as a one click option. because the person will have already entered the info once. I really do appreciate the quick feedback and example. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you use Jquery?

Comment: I've edit the answer for an onClick event.

Comment: Thank you for the help, that has gotten me much closer to my goal.